# Dealing with a warning message from prop.test in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, proportion, error-message

I did a `prop.test` for my data and I got this warning message :

```
Warning messages:
1: In prop.test(x = c(..4, ..12), n = c(..6, ..14), correct = TRUE) :
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

I did a multiple tests at the same time. The analysis  for the first one is :

```
    2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction

data:  x(89, 104) out of c(109, 147)
X-squared = 3.4442, df = 1, p-value = 0.06347
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.002341254  0.220402791
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.8165138 0.7074830
```

Is this warning message means that the results are incorrect? What should I do to fix this please?

Comment: There is probably just not enough data and you should consider fisher.test as an alternative.

Comment: @Bernhard
Thank you very much for your reply. Can I do prop.test for the ones with high counts and fisher with the ones with low counts? or stick with one test ? please

Comment: You can choose to use `fisher.test` when `prop.test` gives you a warning but you should not at all look at `prop.test`s p-value, so do not test the same thing with different tests until one of the tests turns out significant.

Comment: @Bernhard   one more question please, if my counts have numbers with fractions like 46.6. is it still correct to do fisher or proportion test  ? please

Comment: Counts do not have fractions. If you have fractions, something is going wrong. Please edit the question or put up another question so we understand in which situation you believe, fractions might be necessary.

Comment: @Bernhard
I have some samples that have 0.5 group A and 0.5 group B so the total count will have fraction like 55.5 for A and 44.5 for B for example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136518/discussion-between-marwah-al-kaabi-and-bernhard).